# How can I create or code to auto increment email, for java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm Working on Automation. 
I have a Student Registration Form. First of all I want to create a loop for five students for five time registrations after that I want to increment in my email. That increment will done after a new student registers.

Like when first student email is `aali3009@outlook.com` after registration when the second student email will auto increment that as `aali3010@gmail.com`.

Kindly suggest to me what I have to do. I'm providing my code. I Need your help.

```
public class Cartus   
{
    private static String email="aali3009@outlook.com";
    public static  void Cartusfill ()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\workspace\\chromeDriver\\chromeDriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://qa-0.ls.vu/v2/landing-page/cartus/en");
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/div")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/div/select/option[2]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("Mohaname");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("0221-1234567");
               {
                    email = email + 1;
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys(email);
               }
            driver.findElementById("submitButton").click();
            System.out.println("Test case succesfully run");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this code. I have added all the random generator in the method. Also i have added an JDBC to check if the mail is in the DB or not

```
    import java.math.BigInteger;
    import java.security.SecureRandom;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Random;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class TestingItTest {

        String commonXpath = "/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div";
        WebDriver driver;
        int email;

        @BeforeClass
        public void beforeClass() {
//Getting the unique id for email
            email = uniqueSessionId();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\workspace\\chromeDriver\\chromeDriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("http://qa-0.ls.vu/v2/landing-page/cartus/en");

        }

        @Test
        public void f() {
            String StudenEmail;

//looping through the email by incrementing the email
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //Creating a new email for every loop
                StudenEmail = "aali" + email + "@outlook.com";

                String Driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/LoginForm";
//Checking for email already exist in DB or not             
try {
                    Class.forName(Driver);
                    Connection Conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "root", "12345");
                    PreparedStatement ps = Conn.prepareStatement("SELECT studenId FROM StudentDetail WHERE email = ?");
                    ps.setString(1, StudenEmail);
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                    if (rs.next()) {
                        // Email Already exist Do something

                    }

//Method to register the email 
                    DotheMailAction(StudenEmail);

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        private void DotheMailAction(String studenEmail2) {
//Method to do the registration
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(commonXpath + "[1]/div")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(commonXpath + "[1]/div/select/option[2]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(commonXpath + "[2]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(commonXpath + "[2]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(commonXpath + "[2]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("Mohaname");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(commonXpath + "[3]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("0221-1234567");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(commonXpath + "[3]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys(studenEmail2);
            driver.findElement(By.id("submitButton")).click();

            email++;
            System.out.println("Test case succesfully run");
        }

        @AfterClass
        public void afterClass() {
//After the process the code closed the driver
            if (driver != null) {
                driver.quit();
            }
        }

        public int nextSessionId() {
            //Random number generator
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            int num = random.nextInt(100000);
            String formatted = String.format("%05d", num);
            Integer formatInt = Integer.valueOf(formatted);
            return formatInt;
        }

        public String nextSessionString() {
            //Random single Char generator
            Random r = new Random();
            char random_3_Char = (char) (48 + r.nextInt(47));
            return random_3_Char + "";
        }

        public int uniqueSessionId() {
            // Every time random unique number generator
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            Date date = new Date();
            Integer formatInt = Integer.valueOf(dateFormat.format(date));
            return formatInt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for Your support but is it possible that if i validate the email on run time test on my browser example when i put from sendkeys(aali3005@gmail.com) browser indicate me to email already exist is it possible to validate my email ???

Comment: Hi Sorry i couldnt understand, you want to validate your email or find if the email already exist or not ?

Comment: Yes i want to validate the email or find if the email already exist or not .

Comment: Then you to do the DB verification this can be done use JDBC

Comment: You can Show me any example ? please

Comment: No one have answer my question :(

Comment: Thanks for your support can you explain this code ?